# I wish to use a single header file in multiple pages using include header.php, but one bit of info in the header.php must differ slightly on each page

Tags: php

Along the top of my html template are nav links to individual pages such as home, contact, about and privacy.
These are the same on each page with one small difference, whichever page you're on is highlighted on the navbar.

This is achieved like this:

```
<li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
```

In the above example, the Home page will be highlighted due to the use of class="current".

But I want to rename my pages as .php and to have the nav links in a separate header.php file which gets included in every page.

But this will mean that only the home page will be highlighted, regardless of what page you're on, as there's only one header.php.

Is there a way to get the class="current" to reflect the particular page name that is being viewed, eg contact.php ?

Something along the lines of class="current" = pagename ?
Or something like that.

Comment: class="current" href="index.php">Home
href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>

Comment: Since you are using `php`. why not use variables to store the name of the current page, then just check if what is the current page, then add your class

Answer (score 0):

You can assign Active class like bellow

Suppose your current page is contact.php

```
<?php
$current_url = 'index.php';
?>
<li <?php if($current_url == 'index.php'){ echo 'class="current"';}?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li <?php if($current_url == 'contact.php'){ echo 'class="current"';}?>><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li <?php if($current_url == 'about.php'){ echo 'class="current"';}?>><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li <?php if($current_url == 'privacy.php'){ echo 'class="current"';}?>><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
```

Comment: This worked first time! I've got to say a very big thank you, you guys are genius and so quick to answer too. I'm still learning and have a long way to go, but I am very impressed!

Comment: Glade to help, you can thank us by just accepting the answer, if you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
$filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // will retrieve the php file name.

<li <?php echo ($filename == 'index.php')? 'class="current"':''; ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
```

Like this to all `<li>` tags

Comment: I've got to say a very big thank you, you guys are genius and so quick to answer too. I'm still learning and have a long way to go, but I am very impressed!